Galois Group of $\mathbb Q$ Surjects onto Certain Cyclotomic Extension
Let $\ell$ be a prime and let $G_{\mathbb Q, \ell}$ denote the Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\mu_{\ell^\infty})/\mathbb Q$, the extension of $\mathbb Q$ formed by adjoining all primitive $\ell^n$th roots of unity for each $n$. Why is the restriction map $G_{\mathbb Q} \to G_{\mathbb Q, \ell}$ surjective?

Do you mean $G_{\mathbb{Q},\ell}=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\ell^{\infty}}))$ or $G_{\mathbb{Q},\ell}=\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\ell^{\infty}})/\mathbb{Q})$? I’m assuming that you mean the latter, otherwise the restriction map is not well-defined.

The latter. Edited!

This ultimately reduces to finite Galois theory using topology. Let me explain.
Claim 1: let $G$ be a compact group, and $H$ be a profinite group and $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a continuous homomorphism such that for any finite index subgroup $U \leq H$, $G \rightarrow H \rightarrow H/U$ is onto. Then $f$ is onto.
Consequence: $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow G_{\mathbb{Q},\ell}$ is onto if, for every $n \geq 1$, $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\ell^n})/\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective.
Proof of the claim: let $h \in H$. For every finite index subgroup $U \leq H$, $G_{h,U}=f^{-1}(hU)$ is a nonempty closed subspace of $G$. Since $G$ is compact, the intersection of the $G_{h,U}$ (over all $U$) is nonempty, because any finite intersection of $G_{h,U}$ is nonempty. Hence, there is $g \in G$ such that for any $U$, $f(g) \in h U$. Hence $f(g)=h$.
Claim 2: let $G$ be the projective limit of a system of finite groups $G_i$ with compatible surjections $p_i: G_i \rightarrow H$ (indexed by positive integers $i$). Then $p: G \rightarrow H$ (given by any projection $G \rightarrow G_i \rightarrow H$) is surjective.
Consequence: for every $n \geq 1$, $G_{\mathbb{Q}} \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{\ell^n})/\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective.
Proof of the claim: let $\Pi$ be the product of the $G_i$ endowed with the product topology. For every $i$, let $\pi_i$ be the projection on the $i$-th coordinate and $\Pi_i \subset \Pi$ the closed subspace given by the condition: for every $j \leq i$, the $j$-th coordinate (in $G_j$) is the image of the $i$-th coordinate (in $G_i$).
Fix an index $i_0$. Then $G\leq \Pi$ is the intersection of the $\Pi_i$, so, if $h \in H$, $h$ is in the image of $G$ if the intersection of all the $\Pi_i \cap (p_{i_0}\circ \pi_{i_0})^{-1}(h)$ is nonempty.
Again, finite intersections of the $\Pi_i \cap (p_{i_0}\circ \pi_{i_0})^{-1}(h)$ are nonempty because every $p_i: G_i \rightarrow H$ is surjective. Since $\Pi$ is compact, the intersection of the $\Pi_i \cap (p_{i_0}\circ \pi_{i_0})^{-1}(h)$ is nonempty, whence the conclusion.

Awesome! I only fail to understand one thing: why does Claim 2's consequence follow from Claim 2? Namely, why are the $G_i \to H$ surjective in our specific case?

Oh! One other thing:  2) Why does the surjectivity of the $p_i$ guarantee that finite intersections of the $\Pi_i \cap ...$ are nonempty?


because the $G_i$ are the Galois groups of extensions $K(\mu_{\ell^n})/\mathbb{Q}$ for ever larger number fields $K/\mathbb{Q}$, and $n$ is fixed.



because a finite intersection of some $\Pi_i \cap \ldots$ contains $\Pi_{j} \cap \ldots$ if $j$ is greater than all $i$ in the intersection, and $\Pi_j\cap \ldots$ is nonempty since $p_j$ is onto.

